# Creating and accessing Postgres in Ruby (without Rails)

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I'm trying to write a simple Ruby script that will store strings and integers in a Postgresql database.  Here's how I'd like it to work:

```
require 'pg'
# if database 'Words' exists
#    name = 'Bud'
#    score = 99
#    replace String1 with 'Bud' and Integer1 with 99 if score > Integer1
# else
#    CREATE database 'Words'
#    INSERT INTO Words (String1, Integer1)
#    VALUES ('Dave', 30)
# end
```

I'd like to basically access this DB as you would a simple array or hash. The reason I'd like to use Postgres instead of a YAML file is because YAML files don't persist on free heroku accounts.

Comment: What did you try so far? I assume a basic search should give you a basic example

Comment: You only `insert` into tables, not "databases". I think you are mixing the terms `table` and `database`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
# Connect to the template1 db (built in)
conn_template1 = PG.connect( dbname: 'template1' )
res1 = conn.exec('SELECT * from pg_database where datname = $1', ['words'])
if res1.ntuples == 1 # db exists
  conn_words = PG.connect(dbname: 'words')
  # ... do stuff to your DB
  conn_words.exec('INSERT INTO words ....')
else
  conn.exec('CREATE DATABASE words')
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm going to play with this right now.  Thanks for the prompt response!

Comment: Thanks Dan. I was able to get everything working on my local machine.  However, when I deploy the script to Heroku, I'm getting an error "initialize': could not connect to server: No such file or directory (PG::ConnectionBad)"

Comment: Oh right. You probably don't have create database permissions on heroku. To be honest for the kind of application I'd recommend Digital Ocean or AWS.

Comment: Although perhaps you could do it with the heroku API. I suggest a separate question on stack overflow